# NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData crashes - No way to catch the exception?

Tags: objective-c, exception

I have the following code:

```
@try {
    NSSet *set = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:mData];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    // Use default data
}
```

At some point it seems that I wasn't archiving properly and `mData` is corrupted.
This gives me the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: 
incomprehensible archive (0x14, 0xffffff9a, 0xffffffd0, 0x1d, 0x9, 0x3d, 0x43, 0x3)'
*** Call stack at first throw:
```

If a try/catch block does not work, how am I supposed to check for an exception here? Shouldn't it be working?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: @PICyourBrain it's been quite a long time now and I don't remember what I did, unfortunately. I didn't have a unit test for that part of the code at that time though, so I'm not sure what the issue was.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the try-catch code wasn't working. The log says "uncaught exception" so this error happens somewhere else in your code.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem and I am definitely using a try catch block as well. In my case it fails to catch it intermittently.